# Cannot invoke "java.net.ServerSocket.close()" because "Server.server" is null

Tags: java, client-server

I'm trying to write a simple client/server application. I have a data on  a client's side, that turns into an integer array and transfers to server. The server makes the calcutaions and returns them to client. But my program falls with this exception.

Sorry for long text, I'm just studying and really need your help.

```
public class Client {

    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static ObjectInputStream in;
    private static ObjectOutputStream out;
    private static int[] parsedValue;

    public Client(String input) {
        try {
            parsedValue = Arrays.stream(input.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Client(int[] input) {
        parsedValue = input;
    }

    public Client(List<Integer> input) {
        try {
            parsedValue = input.stream().mapToInt(d->d).toArray();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {

               clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4004);
               in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
               out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


                String clientTestString = "440,5,16";
                Client stringClient = new Client(clientTestString);
                out.writeObject(stringClient.parsedValue);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println(in.readObject());


                int[] clientIntsTest = {39, 10, 5};
                Client arrayClient = new Client(clientIntsTest);
                out.writeObject(arrayClient.parsedValue);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println(in.readObject());


                List<Integer> clientsTestList = Arrays.asList(781, 9, 7);
                Client listClient = new Client(clientsTestList);
                out.writeObject(listClient.parsedValue);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println(in.readObject());


            } finally {
                System.out.println("Client was closed");
                clientSocket.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

```
public class Server {

    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static ObjectInputStream in;
    private static ObjectOutputStream out;
    private static int[] parsedValue;


    public String getResult() {
        return calculation(parsedValue);
    }


    public String calculation(int[] parsedValue) {
        parsedValue[0] = toDecimal(parsedValue[0], parsedValue[1]);

        String answer = "";
        int temp = 0;
        String digits = new String("ABCDEF");

        while (parsedValue[0] > 0) {
            temp = parsedValue[0] % parsedValue[2];

            if (temp < 10) {
                answer = temp + answer;
            } else {
                answer = digits.charAt(temp - 10) + answer;
            }
            parsedValue[0] /= parsedValue[2];
        }

        return answer;
    }

    public int toDecimal(int value, int baseNotation) {
        int i = 0;
        int decimalNumber = 0;
        if (value > 0) {
            while (value != 0) {
                decimalNumber += (value % 10) * Math.pow(baseNotation, i);
                value /= 10;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return decimalNumber;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(4004);
                System.out.println("Server runs");

                clientSocket = server.accept();

                try {

                    in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                    parsedValue = (int[]) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(parsedValue);
                    Server examp = new Server();
                    String answer = examp.getResult();
                    System.out.println(answer);
                    out.writeObject(answer);
                    out.flush();


                } finally {
                    clientSocket.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Server closed");
                server.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this two lines

```
   Server examp = new Server();
   String answer = examp.getResult();
```

you cretat a new object which overriddes the field `private static ServerSocket server;`

A better solution is to put the logic from your main() into a seperate method like run(), instantiate in main() a new object of server and call the run() on it. Dont't forget to make all fields as instance members by removing the `static` keyword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server examp = new Server();
    examp.run();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4004);
        System.out.println("Server runs");

        clientSocket = server.accept();

        try {

            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            parsedValue = (int[]) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(parsedValue);
            String answer = getResult();
            System.out.println(answer);
            out.writeObject(answer);
            out.flush();


        } finally {
            clientSocket.close();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Server closed");
            server.close();
        }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

By the way: You should always use this patern to get out of the 'static-trap'. So I suggest you refactor your Client calss too.

Comment: I've solve my problem, thank you very much!!!